# Hibernate Search, Infinispan and clustering with JGroups

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search, infinispan

We are attempting to use Hibernate Search in our project together with Infinispan. We have looked in the documentation and tried the easiest configuration, just to define Infinispan as provider. When starting the application (deployed in Tomcat) on two machines on the network, the index on both machines are updated individually but there is no communication between the machines.

This is my configuration.
We are using default tcp communication. What could be wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:7.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-7.0.xsd
                    urn:infinispan:config:store:jdbc:7.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-cachestore-jdbc-config-7.0.xsd"
xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:7.0"
xmlns:jdbc="urn:infinispan:config:store:jdbc:7.0">

<!-- *************************** -->
<!-- System-wide global settings -->
<!-- *************************** -->
<jgroups>
    <!-- Note that the JGroups transport uses sensible defaults if no configuration
        property is defined. See the JGroupsTransport javadocs for more flags.
        jgroups-udp.xml is the default stack bundled in the Infinispan core jar: integration
        and tuning are tested by Infinispan. -->
  <stack-file name="default-jgroups-tcp" path="default-configs/default-jgroups-tcp.xml" />
</jgroups>

<cache-container name="HibernateSearch" default-cache="default" statistics="false" shutdown-hook="DONT_REGISTER">

    <transport stack="default-jgroups-tcp" cluster="venkatcluster"/>

    <!-- Duplicate domains are allowed so that multiple deployments with default configuration
        of Hibernate Search applications work - if possible it would be better to use JNDI to share
        the CacheManager across applications -->
    <jmx duplicate-domains="true" />

     <!-- *************************************** -->
     <!--  Cache to store Lucene's file metadata  -->
     <!-- *************************************** -->
     <replicated-cache name="LuceneIndexesMetadata" mode="SYNC" remote-timeout="25000">
        <transaction mode="NONE"/>
        <state-transfer enabled="true" timeout="480000" await-initial-transfer="true" />
        <indexing index="NONE" />
        <locking striping="false" acquire-timeout="10000" concurrency-level="500" write-skew="false" />
        <eviction max-entries="-1" strategy="NONE"/>
        <expiration max-idle="-1"/>
        <persistence passivation="false">
            <jdbc:string-keyed-jdbc-store preload="true" fetch-state="true" read-only="false" purge="false">
                <property name="key2StringMapper">org.infinispan.lucene.LuceneKey2StringMapper</property>
                <jdbc:connection-pool connection-url="jdbc:mysql://192.168.2.15:3306/entityindex" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" password="pf_user1!" username="pf_user"></jdbc:connection-pool>
                <jdbc:string-keyed-table drop-on-exit="false" create-on-start="true" prefix="ISPN_STRING_TABLE">
                    <jdbc:id-column name="ID" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
                    <jdbc:data-column name="DATA" type="BLOB"/>
                    <jdbc:timestamp-column name="TIMESTAMP" type="BIGINT"/>
                </jdbc:string-keyed-table>
            </jdbc:string-keyed-jdbc-store>
        </persistence>
     </replicated-cache>

     <!-- **************************** -->
     <!--  Cache to store Lucene data  -->
     <!-- **************************** -->
     <distributed-cache name="LuceneIndexesData" mode="SYNC" remote-timeout="25000">
        <transaction mode="NONE"/>
        <state-transfer enabled="true" timeout="480000" await-initial-transfer="true" />
        <indexing index="NONE" />
        <locking striping="false" acquire-timeout="10000" concurrency-level="500" write-skew="false" />
        <eviction max-entries="-1" strategy="NONE"/>
        <expiration max-idle="-1"/>
        <persistence passivation="false">
            <jdbc:string-keyed-jdbc-store preload="true" fetch-state="true" read-only="false" purge="false">
                <property name="key2StringMapper">org.infinispan.lucene.LuceneKey2StringMapper</property>
                <jdbc:connection-pool connection-url="jdbc:mysql://192.168.2.15:3306/entityindex" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" password="pf_user1!" username="pf_user"></jdbc:connection-pool>
                <jdbc:string-keyed-table drop-on-exit="false" create-on-start="true" prefix="ISPN_STRING_TABLE">
                    <jdbc:id-column name="ID" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
                    <jdbc:data-column name="DATA" type="BLOB"/>
                    <jdbc:timestamp-column name="TIMESTAMP" type="BIGINT"/>
                </jdbc:string-keyed-table>
            </jdbc:string-keyed-jdbc-store>
        </persistence>
     </distributed-cache>

     <!-- ***************************** -->
     <!--  Cache to store Lucene locks  -->
     <!-- ***************************** -->
    <replicated-cache name="LuceneIndexesLocking" mode="SYNC" remote-timeout="25000">
        <transaction mode="NONE"/>
        <state-transfer enabled="true" timeout="480000" await-initial-transfer="true" />
        <indexing index="NONE" />
        <locking striping="false" acquire-timeout="10000" concurrency-level="500" write-skew="false" />
        <eviction max-entries="-1" strategy="NONE"/>
        <expiration max-idle="-1"/>
        <persistence passivation="false">
            <jdbc:string-keyed-jdbc-store preload="true" fetch-state="true" read-only="false" purge="false">
                <property name="key2StringMapper">org.infinispan.lucene.LuceneKey2StringMapper</property>
                <jdbc:connection-pool connection-url="jdbc:mysql://192.168.2.15:3306/entityindex" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" password="pf_user1!" username="pf_user"></jdbc:connection-pool>
                <jdbc:string-keyed-table drop-on-exit="false" create-on-start="true" prefix="ISPN_STRING_TABLE">
                    <jdbc:id-column name="ID" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
                    <jdbc:data-column name="DATA" type="BLOB"/>
                    <jdbc:timestamp-column name="TIMESTAMP" type="BIGINT"/>
                </jdbc:string-keyed-table>
            </jdbc:string-keyed-jdbc-store>
        </persistence>
    </replicated-cache>

</cache-container>
```

Comment: The #1 reason for not clustering properly is configuration on dual-stack machines. Try setting -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Answer (score 2):

You likely need to make some adjustments either to your local network configuration or to the JGroups configuration files.

The default configuration being included with Infinispan is designed to work out of the box in most cases, but it's not possible to make sure of that: networks can be setup in many different ways.

I would suggest testing this first on a loopback network by running the two Tomcat instances on the same machine, make sure you can make that work first.

A useful step in setting up a JGroups based cluster is to run one of the JGroups demos first; they are very simple and might help to confirm your basic configuration is fine.

## Running a JGroups demo

The JGroups jar includes some simple demos. It doesn't need any dependency so it's easy to run directly from a commandline.

See [the JGroups documentation](http://www.jgroups.org/tutorial-3.x/html/ch01.html#d0e92) for several examples.

## Test your custom configuration using the JGroups demo

Once you have a demo running across multiple machines, use it to test your custom configuration files.

N.B. you might need to adjust some of your network routing options, for example many systems don't have a reasonable default for multicast IP.

Also check the amount of hops across the network your packets have to walk through. In JGroups configuration files you'll find a *ip_ttl* setting, if it's not high enough your packets will be dropped by the routers before reaching their destination.

Comment: Now the data is syncing between systems. I see that when multiple people are accessing the system, Indexes are getting dropped what could be the problem.